# What is the Parent Tag for <edit-config in config,xml in cordova ios project?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-camera

I update an iOS app and it was rejected with below email

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

I try to add below xml tag to config.xml.

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
    <string>Need camera access to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
    <string>Need to photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
</edit-config>
```

But I am not sure under which tag I need to

**My config.xml file.**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.aotsinc.christian.iphone.biblequizcompanion" version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Bible Quiz Companion</name>
    <description>
        Bible Quiz Companion is a free app useful for the users to prepare for Jounior Bible Quiz Compatition.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Alpha Omega Tech Solutions Inc.
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-tts" spec="^0.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-apprate" spec="^1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot" spec="git+https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot.git" />
</widget>
```

Thanks for your help

**EDIT 1**

I try to add the code that you gave in plugin.xml inside camera plugin as below.  But I didn't see this entry in the  info.plist. Can you please tell me whether my change in the plugin.xml is correct. Thanks

```
<platform name="ios">
         <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
             <feature name="Camera">
                 <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
             </feature>
             <preference name="CameraUsesGeolocation" value="false" />
         </config-file>

         <js-module src="www/ios/CameraPopoverHandle.js" name="CameraPopoverHandle">
            <clobbers target="CameraPopoverHandle" />
         </js-module>

         <preference name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
          <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription">
               <string>Need camera access to take pictures</string>
          </config-file>
          <preference name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
          <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
               <string>Need to photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
          </config-file>

         <header-file src="src/ios/UIImage+CropScaleOrientation.h" />
         <source-file src="src/ios/UIImage+CropScaleOrientation.m" />
         <header-file src="src/ios/CDVCamera.h" />
         <source-file src="src/ios/CDVCamera.m" />
         <header-file src="src/ios/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.h" />
         <source-file src="src/ios/CDVJpegHeaderWriter.m" />
         <header-file src="src/ios/CDVExif.h" />
         <framework src="ImageIO.framework" weak="true" />
         <framework src="CoreLocation.framework" />
         <framework src="CoreGraphics.framework" />
         <framework src="AssetsLibrary.framework" />
         <framework src="MobileCoreServices.framework" />
         <framework src="CoreGraphics.framework" />
         <framework src="AVFoundation.framework" />

     </platform>
```

Answer (score 3):

[see docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#ios-quirks)

In your `config.xml` as a child node of `<platform name="ios">` add:

```
<edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need to photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
</edit-config>
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to be working anymore, as of cordova 8.xx and phonegap 8.x The resulting plist only contains a single string entry, starting with Privacy - <your content here>, and not a key value pair as it should be. ugh.

Answer (score 2):

Use **config-file** instead of **edit-config** below **PLATFORM** tag in **PLUGIN.XML** file of your plugin that need this:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription">
         <string>Need camera access to take pictures</string>
    </config-file>
    <preference name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" default=" " />
    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
         <string>Need to photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Comment: I try to add the xml code that you gave in plugin.xml inside camera plugin directory. But I didn't see this new entry in the info.plist. Can you please tell me whether my change in the plugin.xml is correct. I edit my original question with EDIT 1 as title. Thanks

Comment: What version of camera plugin and cordova are you using? In latest version of cordova-plugin-camera this config are altready added in plugin.xml.. [https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)

Comment: Thank you @Frix33, had same problem with cordova-plugin-contacts, using config-file instead of edit-config seems to work.